# Prometheus java client and Prometheus server compatiblity

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

Current latest version of [Prometheus Java client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/releases) is 0.9.0 and the latest version of [Prometheus Server](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases) is 2.20.1. I was wondering if there is a compatibility matrix of client and server versions which I could *not* find via basic google search. If someone is aware of it, can you please share?

It can contain something like the earliest supported version of server for the latest client and also vice-versa, the earliest supported version of client for the latest server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically speaking, everything should work with everything.

The current v0.0.4 Prometheus text format has been around for 5+ years, you'd probably have to dig back to before the Java simpleclient existed to find something incompatible.